# Rails Way for Form Validation + No Submit Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

Currently I am using jQuery to handle this but it's less than optimal - I can emulate bugs within it quite often (Submit button requiring me to click back into fields multiple times.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    validate();
    $('#required_field1, #required_field2, #required_field3, #required_field4, #required_field5, #required_field6').change(validate);
});

function validate(){
    if ($('#required_field1').val().length   >   0   &&
        $('#required_field2').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('#required_field3').val().length    >   0 &&
        $('#required_field4').val().length    >   0 &&
        $('#required_field5').val().length    >   0 
        ){
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

But it also doesn't feel proper for Rails, at all. While I understand the concept of data-binding isn't friendly to it, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this within Rails?

Currently without it you can Submit a blank page, and get an error immediately, which is much worse experience than this.

Appreciate any feedback.

Rails 5 + Bootstrap3(Not that it matters for this.)

Comment: If the fields are columns of table, then why not using rails way of validation like: `validate :required_field1, presence: true`...

Comment: @Abhi That's basically what I'm asking - Does that get passed into the submit button? Or are you talking about within the Model?

Comment: Yes, if the fields that you have mentioned are DB columns, then you must let rails handle the validations [Rails Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Comment: @Abhi Thanks - This helps me handle the back-end validation, but is there a better Rails way to make the Submit button UN-clickable until all forms have been filled? Or is the jQuery method I have the only one?

Comment: I have posted an answer, which I feel would be cleaner when number of fields are a lot. BTW, in your code, you need to call validate inside function like: `$('#required_field1, #required_field2, ...').change(function() { validate() });`

Answer (score 0):

I would use [jQuery's serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/):

Eg:

```
var params = jQuery("#form_id").serializeArray();

//This should give you form params like:
// [
//   {name: "obj[required_field1]", value: ""},
//   {name: "obj[required_field2]", value: ""},
//   .
//   .
//   .
// ]

jQuery.each(params, function(i, v) {
  if(v["value"].length > 0) {
    jQuery("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    jQuery("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

**NOTE:** This is just an example to make you understand the concept(as I don't have your HTML/Rails template).

**EDIT**

Put this logic to change event of each text field.

```
jQuery("#required_field1, #required_field2, ...").change(function() {
  // Above code goes here
});
```